# reconstructing matched data set from R's matching package

Tags: r, propensity-scores

I am using Mebane and Sekhon's [Matching](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Matching/) package for R, and my goal is to make casual inferences about a proportion and a mean.  The proportion is straight forward, but the mean has missing values, which `Match` does not accept.  My approach is trying to get access to the matched records through the row indexes, but the results are not quite right.

Example code:

```
require(Matching)
demo(DehejiaWahba)
# mean before matching
by(lalonde$u75, lalonde$treat, mean)
# mean after matching
matched <- rbind(lalonde[rr$index.treated,], 
  lalonde[rr$index.control,])
by(matched$u75, matched$treat, mean)
```

The output of the demo shows the matched means for u75 are 0.6 and 0.62072:

```
***** (V14) u75 *****
                   Before Matching           After Matching
mean treatment........        0.6                       0.6 
mean control..........    0.68462                   0.62072
```

However, the reconstructed data set has different means:

```
    matched$treat: 0
    [1] 0.7861272
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    matched$treat: 1
    [1] 0.7543353
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Charlie suggested, using the weights does give means that "match Match."

```
weighted.mean(lalonde[rr$index.control,]$u75, rr$weights)
weighted.mean(lalonde[rr$index.treated,]$u75, rr$weights)
```

Answer (score 3):

See that `matched` has 692 observations. Now take a look at `summary(rr)`. You'll see that there are 346 *unweighted* matched pairs--that is, several of the treated observations were matched to several control observations. You can see using `summary(rr$weights)` that there is at least one treatment observation that is matched to 12 controls. Without using the weights in your last line, you're getting the wrong answer.